# .load vs .get in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am reading about AJAX in jQuery in the book jQuery in Action.  There is some code which loads html into a div with an onchange event in a select dropdown.  Using `$.get` looks like this:

```
$(function() {

  $('#bootChooserControl').change(function(event){
    $.get(
      '/fetch_product_details',
      $(this).serialize()
    );
  });
});
```

I have my controller respond to JavaScript:

**fetch_product_details.js.erb**

```
$('#productDetailPane').html('<%= j render "product_details" %>');
```

Now the next example switches to `$.load` and looks like this:

```
$('#bootChooserControl').change(function(event){
  $('#productDetailPane').load(
    '/fetch_product_details',
    $(this).serialize()
});
```

But for some reason the `#productDetailPane` is now filled with the following text:

```
$('#productDetailPane').html('
\n Item name:<\/label> Chippewa 17-inch Engineer Boot\n<\/div>\n
\n SKU:<\/label> 7141832\n<\/div>\n
\n Height:<\/label> 17 inches\n<\/div>\n
\n Colors:<\/label> Black Oi
...
```

Just curious why the `$.load` function does not interpret the JavaScript?

Comment: is the response from /fetch_product_details encoded perhaps?

Comment: It's that because that's what you return from your server.

Comment: You shouldn't be returning Javascript from the controller, you should just return the HTML.